# If Statement Contains Only "True"

Tags: c#, if-statement, vb6

I am converting a vb6 app into c# and I've come across something I don't quite understand. I've never seen an if statement structure where the expression being evaluated is literally "true" or "false".

```
    private bool InitializeForProgramming()      //OK
    {
      if (J1939.getReplyStatus() == modJ1939.dmOpFailed)             //or OpComplete (dmBusy auto cycles)
      {
        //check the Pointer value to see if engineRunning, or already in Mode
        if (true)                                //let it proceed             ***  ??
        {
          //nothing to do
        }
        else
        {
          lblCommun.Text = "ProgramMode Failed!";
          lblCommun.ForeColor = Color.Red;

          //could report more detailed reasons! (engineRunning, etc.)
          return true;             //FAILED!
        }

      }
```

What is being evaluated here with the expression if(true)? If what is true?

Here is the original vb6 code:

```vb
Private Function InitializeForProgramming() As Boolean      'OK
If getReplyStatus = dmOpFailed Then             'or OpComplete (dmBusy auto cycles)
'check the Pointer value to see if engineRunning, or already in Mode
If (True) Then                                'let it proceed             ***  ??
  'nothing to do
Else
  txtCommun.Text = "ProgramMode Failed!"
  txtCommun.ForeColor = vbRed

  'could report more detailed reasons! (engineRunning, etc.)
  InitializeForProgramming = True             'FAILED!
  Exit Function
End If
End If
```

Please let me know if you need me to include anything else to help me get an answer.

Comment: I love this line `InitializeForProgramming = True 'FAILED!`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely this is the result of a condition that was removed in the past. I.e. there used to be a condition in the `if`, but not any longer. You should check the source control history for changes to that line.

You can just remove the whole `if` statement in this case for your rewrite. Also C# probably complains that not all code paths return a value from the method.

Comment: Plus one. It looks like long ago someone made a quick hack. I notice the stars and question-marks in the original comment. `let it proceed             ***  ??`

Answer (score 1):

You are going right man, It is doing nothing by the code if(true) in vb6. Go ahead with your code

Answer (score 1):

That could not be right, I think that *else* statement should be outside matching its parent. Otherwise that *if (true)* was something else before and for debugging reasons was left there as true

Answer (score 1):

the if (true)   does not mean anything in that case, but it seems like the else is an Exception catch or an OnError.

In C# you should just use a try/catch here.

Answer (score 1):

Someone before think that a validation must be done:

```
    //check the Pointer value to see if engineRunning, or already in Mode
```

Maybe is requirement that hasn't been developed yet.

```
if (true)
```

means always, similar to:

```
if (1 == 1)
```